# What are the ways to reference a dimension/attribute/measure in mdx?

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

I need to analyse user queries for Olap Cube to find out which dimensions, attributes and measures aren't used. My idea is to use a list of names of dimensions, attributes and measures and find out how many times were they used with regular expressions. However, I need to be sure that I haven't missed any formatting options and I don't really know MDX. My assumptions are:

**Dimension**: Dimension name is always enclosed by square brackets [] or by apostroves '' [['] dimensionName []']

**Attribute**: Attribute is always preceeded by it's dimension formatted as above and enclosed in square brackets  [['] dimensionName []'].[attributeName]

**Measure**: Measure is always enclosed by square brackets, of surrounded with arithmetical operation signs, or combination of these two

Are those assumptions correct? If not, how can I improve them to cover all cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Measures] is a dimension as well.

- [Measures].[**MeasureName**] — the measure was used.
- [**DimensionName**].[**AttributeName**] — the dimension and its
  attribute were used.